# Windows 10 Pro rdp concurrent local and remote

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have two users on Windows 10 Pro computer, both with administrative privileges. One needs to work locally and the other remotely - through RDP. Right now windows asks local user to disconnect upon RDP logon and vice versa. Is there a way to enable simultaneous login ?

I know Windows has license limitation on concurrent RDP sessions but mine is a different case - just one RDP connection.

Comment: You need a terminal services license. A physical user will need to access the Admin console, and the other a terminal console.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I had a feeling it'a also a license matter.